# Linqtoxml filtering not working

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview, filtering

I am fallowing a tutorial on the internet I use xml file [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669170.aspx)  .I think missed out something .Because Nothing happens Just a blank page appears.What I am doing wrong again.How can i bind filtered data to gridview

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XElement root = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("PurchaseOrders.xml"));
    IEnumerable<XElement> purchaseOrders =
        from el in root.Elements("PurchaseOrder")
        where
            (from add in el.Elements("Address")
             where
                 (string)add.Attribute("Type") == "Shipping" &&
                 (string)add.Element("State") == "NY"
             select add)
            .Any()
        select el;
    foreach (XElement el in purchaseOrders)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = el;
    }
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently looking for elements in the unnamed namespace - whereas the file you've linked to has a namespace URI of `"http://www.adventure-works.com"` for the elements you're looking for.

Just use:

```
XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
IEnumerable<XElement> purchaseOrders =
from el in root.Elements(aw + "PurchaseOrder")
where
    (from add in el.Elements(aw + "Address")
     where
         (string)add.Attribute("Type") == "Shipping" &&
         (string)add.Element(aw + "State") == "NY"
     select add)
    .Any()
select el;
```

Or slightly more simply, IMO:

```
XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
IEnumerable<XElement> purchaseOrders =
    root.Elements(aw + "PurchaseOrder")
        .Where(order => order.Elements(aw + "Address")
                 .Any(add => (string) add.Attribute(aw + "Type") == "Shipping"
                          && (string) add.Element(aw + "State") == "NY"));
```

(Basically this doesn't use query expressions because they're not actually helping you here, and I'm using the `Any` overload which takes a predicate...)